# Android + Realm: fetch data from multiple realms

Tags: android, realm

My data is structured as follows: I do have a huge database of addresses which I would like to prefill when delivering my Android app, then I have some user data which uses/links to those addresses.

I would love to save the addresses in one realm and the user data in another one. The reason for this is that I can easily replace the addresses-realm whenever I submit a new app version to have the latest data available to the user.

The problem I'm facing now is how I can achieve a join over both realms, i.e. fetch user data and its according address. I need to read e.g. `Person` records (coming from the user-realm) with an attached `Address` record (coming from the prefilled realm). Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You would need to map between the realms and their respective queries manually.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently supported to join multiple RealmResuls from separate databases unless you manually match entries to entries.

That being said, there are multiple ways to achieve what you are looking for. In one way, I'd codify the addresses and match users with them as plenty of geographical applications do.

Comment: what do you mean by "manually match entries to entries"? What do you mean by "codify the addresses"? Doesn't really help currently...

Answer (score 0):

No, currently Realm does not have support for combining results from multiple Realms. You will have to do that manually somehow.

Depending on your use case, it can be done in a number of ways. One way is a helper method on the Person object:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
  private String name
  private String addressId; // Id in Address Realm

  public Address getAddress(Realm addressRealm) {
    return addressRealm.where(Address.class).equalTo("id", addressId).findFirst();
  }
}
```

I would be cautious about doing this in a List however as you are triggering a lot of queries that way. Also change listeners and queries will not work across Realms either.